# SQL Server VARCHAR(2) join performance vs. INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string

I have a table of q-grams (2 letter strings). I need to join another table to this on the CHAR(2) field.

Would it be faster to convert these 2-grams into a number (e.g. aa=1, ab=2, ac=3) and convert the fields in both this table and the referencing table to an INT and join using an INT rather?

Kind regards

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. And if you were, it would be better to use a smallint instead of an int. Also, I'm not sure it makes any sense to have a varchar(2) column. There is extra overhead in having varchar columns, and at most you are saving only a single byte.

How many rows of data will you have?

Comment: I'm talking a table with 3 million rows linked to around 150 million q-grams. So a large data set. – Peter 0 secs ago

Comment: Randy, I made a mistake -- it is a CHAR(2) not a VARCHAR(2)

Answer (score 1):

**NO**, this will probably not be more performant, and in addition, you will have to have an additional table to store these mappings.

This will be an additional *JOIN* aswell.

Just remember to apply the correct indexes for your join columns.

Comment: I mean replacing the CHAR(2) column with an INT column, so no mapping table will be needed.

Comment: NO, I still do not think you need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Will that be your bottle neck? Will it be worth the additional complexity?

That said, you might as well make it `CHAR(2)`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake - it is CHAR(2)

Comment: I'm talking a table with 3 million rows linked to around 150 million q-grams. So a large data set.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, changing the key for one join from a string (especially CHAR(2)) to an INT will not make a measurable difference.  This is because most of your overhead is I/O instead of CPU.

Once you get into longer strings, (especially Unicode strings), you can start measuring a difference.  But even then, I think it has more to do with increased I/O due to record size in the data and the indexes.